# pillow instalación error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip, pillow

Tengo problemas al instalar dentro de mi entorno virtual `pillow`:

```
$ sudo pip install pillow
```

He tratado por todas partes y revisé la [documentación oficial](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

También instalé:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools
```

También probé versiones anteriores:

```
$ sudo pip install pillow==2.9
```

Actualicé `pip` y sin mas, me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que otra información muestra el log ?

Comment: disculpa y como me fijo lo del log

Comment: Quité la etiqueta [tag:django] ya que es un tema de instalacion relacionado solo a Python

Comment: Porfavor incluye el error como texto y no como una imagen.

Comment: @CésarBustíos la etiqueta de terminal es inapropiada, no?

Comment: @FabiánHerediaMontiel tienes razon, en todo caso solo sería: [tag:python], [tag:pip], [tag:pillow]

Comment: No tienes gcc. Eso dice el error

Answer (score 9):

Me pasó alguna vez, asegurate antes de instalar en tu sistema todas las dependencias con respecto a las librerías de compilación, imágenes y fonts:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev
```

### Actualización:

El error `DistributionNotFound` ocurre normalmente si mezclas `pip` con `easy_install` para instalar los paquetes de Python, intenta corregir con el siguiente comando:

```
$ easy_install --upgrade pip
```

### Importante:

Recuerda que si estás dentro de tu ambiente virtual, no es necesario usar `sudo` para usar el comando `pip`, basta con usar `pip install paquete`.

Comment: ahora me marca este error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2711, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6

Comment: @HenrryJSairitupac mira la actualización

Answer (score 8):

Esto no responde a la pregunta, pero me parece importante escribirlo.

[Nunca](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial#Python.27s_distutils), [*nunca*](http://workaround.org/easy-install-debian), [***nunca***](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Why-is-pip-not-mentioned-in-the-Installation-Documentation-tp39779p39812.html) uses `sudo pip install`. Puedes sobreescribir paquetes del sistema y desestabilizarlo de formas impredecibles que son casi imposibles de depurar.

Alternativas:

- Usa `pip install --user` para instalar en tu carpeta personal. [En futuras versiones de pip este será el comportamiento por defecto](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668).
- Usa [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) o [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/) para crear entornos de desarrollo aislados y seguros.
- Usa otro gestor de paquetes, como [`conda`](http://conda.io). No necesitas un compilador ya que instala directamente binarios.

Y por último: **no** uses `easy_install`. No puedes desinstalar paquetes, no puedes instalar formato wheel, no puedes listar los paquetes instalados y no puedes instalar listas de requisitos ([Fuente](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pip_easy_install/#pip-vs-easy-install)). [`pip` es la herramienta recomendada por la Python Packaging Authority (PyPA)](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current/).