# CMD pip install error. Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

> ```
> C:\Users\pcort>pip install virtualenv
> Collecting virtualenv
>   Using cached virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Installing collected packages: virtualenv
> Exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ```

Yo he leído que este problema se soluciona usando el comando "sudo" en OSX y "runas" en cmd, con el comando "sudo" solo hay que escribir "sudo pip install ..." y funciona pero, como funciona el comando "runas"? por que si pones "runas pip install ..." no funciona

Comment: Pablo, el idioma de este sitio es el Español. Traduce tu pregunta, por favor.

Comment: Ya lo hice, gracias

Comment: Pablo, la información importante del error está en las últimas líneas. Sin el error completo no podemos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

He probado esto y funciona bien para mí:

```
runas /user:tu_usuario_administrador "pip install virtualenv"
```

Seguido te pedirá la contraseña para `tu_usuario_administrador`.

Luego queda:

```
Escriba la contraseña para tu_usuario_administrador:
Intentando iniciar pip install virtualenv como usuario "Nombre_del_equipo\tu_usuario_administrador" ...
```

Y aparece la ventana de python instalando *virtualenv*.

Un ejemplo más "real" sería:

```
runas /user:Pablo "pip install virtualenv"

Escriba la contraseña para Pablo:
Intentando iniciar pip install virtualenv como usuario "EQUIPO\Pablo" ...
```

Si no te sirvió, te dejo unos enlaces donde puedes consultar más de esto:

Sitio: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249705/how-to-run-an-application-as-run-as-administrator-from-the-command-prompt).

Sitio: [technet microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05cce5f6-3c3a-4bb8-8b72-8c1ce4b5eff1/how-to-run-a-program-as-adminitrator-via-the-command-line?forum=w7itproappcompat)

### Edit

Lee los comentarios para conocer posibles *pitfalls* de ejecutar `pip` como administrador con el comando `runas`

Comment: Es mejor no usar **nunca** `sudo pip install` https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/849/74